# AWS. Trying to make 2 machines be network available

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, vpc

I have two machines on AWS. Both of them are on the Default VPC, the same subnet, the same IP range, but I'm unable to make them network reachable. Both machines have Windows Server 2012. One of them can see the other one through the browser (I have IIS installed on one of them and the security group allows them to see be seen through TCP/IP). But whenever I try to share files and resources between them, even with the same accounts with the same passwords, they can't seem to see each other. I've read through some AWS documentation and it seems I'm doing everything according to the docs, but I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong in the AWS console. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Check security group in AWS and also check windows file sharing is enabled and appropriate ports are opened with windows firewall.

Comment: Security group is the same in AWS, file sharing is enabled. I will try disabling (for now) the firewall. Thanks.

Comment: the gist of @Jordan's comment is that the ports for the applications you are attempting to use have to be open between the machines in the security group that's configured

Comment: That does make more sense. I will try that approach (enabling the ports in the rules for such security group). Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is may be because of the security group(AWS firewall).
Ensure that the inbound rule of the instance which you are trying to connect 
has the ssh port open for the ip range of instance you try to connect from.

You can change inbound rule as follows:

Ec2-> Running Instances -> Select your instance -> Select the security group associated with the instance -> Inbound